# How to count rows in excel by using text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the total rows of in a section of an excel sheet. My problem is that my formula needs to account for rows being added and removed both in the section and above the section. Using functions =ROWS(A14:A20) and =ROWS(INDIRECT("A14:A"&ROW()-1)) won't work because if I add a row under row A8 now my function needs to be A15:A21. I have text in both the top and bottom rows that will always be consistent, is there a way to write a function using the text as a start and stopping point for my row count?

Comment: Use MATCH......

Comment: Relative range references _will_ update when you insert rows either above or in the refered to range.

Comment: You can create a dynamic named range and reference that name in your formula.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right path. Making MATCH nested in a SUM function yielded the correct results. I ended up with =SUM(MATCH("Completed ",A:A,0))-(MATCH("Start",A:A,0))-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the section starts with *alpha* in column **A** and end with *omega*, use:

```
=MATCH("omega",A:A,0)-MATCH("alpha",A:A,0)+1
```